# "Incremental / Decremental" SVM Algorithm - That can be trained on additional data

Tags: python-2.7, svm, libsvm

I am training an SVM model(RBF kernel) on ~ 5000 samples, I tunned my model properly and used it to make predictions.

Now, I have 1000 more samples which can also be used for training. 
My question is, do I have to make the model again on total 6000 samples, or is there any way by which I can add training data to my existing SVM model.

Note- Actually the dataset I am using is quite large, and making model again will not be a good thought.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to redo the training with the whole training set.

Comment: Thankyou, @stefan I guess I have to do that only. But I also heard of "Incremental SVM", I don't know much about that, but maybe this can be used to re-train with new data only.

Answer (score 0):

Its called "incremental" or "online" SVM algorithm. Currently its supported mostly for linear kernel type in various libraries:

1. [Liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/ws/) Incremental. [Paper](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvmtools/warm-start/warm-start.pdf)
2. [Gert Cauwenberghs](https://isn.ucsd.edu/svm/incremental/)
3. [Chris Diehl](https://www.cpdiehl.org/code.html)